# What is a clean way to convert a Result into an Option?

Tags: rust, option-type

Before updating to a more recent Rust version the following used to work:

```
fn example(val: &[&str]) {
    let parsed_value: Vec<usize> = val
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|e| e.parse::<usize>())
        .collect();
}
```

However, now the parse method returns a `Result` type instead of an `Option` and I get the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:25
  |
4 |         .filter_map(|e| e.parse::<usize>())
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found enum `std::result::Result`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::option::Option<_>`
             found type `std::result::Result<usize, std::num::ParseIntError>`
```

I could create an `Option` through a conditional, but is there a better / cleaner way?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok). Types added for clarity:

```
let res: Result<u8, ()> = Ok(42);
let opt: Option<u8> = res.ok();
println!("{:?}", opt);
```

For symmetry's sake, there's also [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) and [`Option::ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else) to go from an `Option` to a `Result`.

---

In your case, you have an iterator.

If you'd like to *ignore* failures, use [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map). Since `Result` (and `Option`) implement `IntoIterator`, this works:

```
let parsed_value: Vec<usize> = val
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|e| e.parse())
    .collect();
```

If you'd like to stop on the first failure, you can `collect` into one big `Result`. This is less obvious, but you can check out the implementors of [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E) for the full list of `collect`-able items.

```
let parsed_value: Result<Vec<usize>, _> = val
    .iter()
    .map(|e| e.parse())
    .collect();
```

Of course, you can then convert the one big `Result` into an `Option`, as the first example shows.